# Compilation error: hidden symbol `__aeabi_uidiv'

Tags: compilation, compiler-errors, raspberry-pi

I try to compile [FingerJetFXOSE](https://github.com/FingerJetFXOSE/FingerJetFXOSE) on my RaspberryPi, but it always fails with the following output / error:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/work/iso_conv/FingerJetFXOSE-master $ make
make -C src/libFRFXLL
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/work/iso_conv/FingerJetFXOSE-master/src/libFRFXLL'
make -C src/libFRFXLL
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/work/iso_conv/FingerJetFXOSE-master/src/libFRFXLL/src/libFRFXLL'
g++ -O2 -I../algorithm -I../../include -I../../src/include -I../../../ExternalDependencies/STL/STLport-5.2.1/stlport -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-stack-protector -fPIC -DFRFXLL_MAJOR=5 -DFRFXLL_MINOR=2 -DFRFXLL_REVISION=0 -DFRFXLL_BUILD=0   -c -o FRFXLLCreateFeatureSetInPlaceFromRaw.o FRFXLLCreateFeatureSetInPlaceFromRaw.cpp
ar rv ../../lib/libFRFXLL.a FRFXLLCreateFeatureSetInPlaceFromRaw.o
ar: creating ../../lib/libFRFXLL.a
a - FRFXLLCreateFeatureSetInPlaceFromRaw.o
g++ -O2 -I../algorithm -I../../include -I../../src/include -I../../../ExternalDependencies/STL/STLport-5.2.1/stlport -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-stack-protector -fPIC -DFRFXLL_MAJOR=5 -DFRFXLL_MINOR=2 -DFRFXLL_REVISION=0 -DFRFXLL_BUILD=0   -c -o FRFXLLCreateContext.o FRFXLLCreateContext.cpp
ar rv ../../lib/libFRFXLL.a FRFXLLCreateContext.o
a - FRFXLLCreateContext.o
g++ -O2 -I../algorithm -I../../include -I../../src/include -I../../../ExternalDependencies/STL/STLport-5.2.1/stlport -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-stack-protector -fPIC -DFRFXLL_MAJOR=5 -DFRFXLL_MINOR=2 -DFRFXLL_REVISION=0 -DFRFXLL_BUILD=0   -c -o FRFXLLCreateFeatureSetInPlace.o FRFXLLCreateFeatureSetInPlace.cpp

ar rv ../../lib/libFRFXLL.a FRFXLLCreateFeatureSetInPlace.o
a - FRFXLLCreateFeatureSetInPlace.o
g++ -O2 -I../algorithm -I../../include -I../../src/include -I../../../ExternalDependencies/STL/STLport-5.2.1/stlport -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-stack-protector -fPIC -DFRFXLL_MAJOR=5 -DFRFXLL_MINOR=2 -DFRFXLL_REVISION=0 -DFRFXLL_BUILD=0   -c -o FRFXLLGetLibraryVersion.o FRFXLLGetLibraryVersion.cpp
ar rv ../../lib/libFRFXLL.a FRFXLLGetLibraryVersion.o
a - FRFXLLGetLibraryVersion.o
g++ -O2 -I../algorithm -I../../include -I../../src/include -I../../../ExternalDependencies/STL/STLport-5.2.1/stlport -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-stack-protector -fPIC -DFRFXLL_MAJOR=5 -DFRFXLL_MINOR=2 -DFRFXLL_REVISION=0 -DFRFXLL_BUILD=0   -c -o FRFXLLExport.o FRFXLLExport.cpp
ar rv ../../lib/libFRFXLL.a FRFXLLExport.o
a - FRFXLLExport.o
g++ -O2 -I../algorithm -I../../include -I../../src/include -I../../../ExternalDependencies/STL/STLport-5.2.1/stlport -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-stack-protector -fPIC -DFRFXLL_MAJOR=5 -DFRFXLL_MINOR=2 -DFRFXLL_REVISION=0 -DFRFXLL_BUILD=0   -c -o FRFXLLCreateFeatureSet.o FRFXLLCreateFeatureSet.cpp
ar rv ../../lib/libFRFXLL.a FRFXLLCreateFeatureSet.o
a - FRFXLLCreateFeatureSet.o
g++ -O2 -I../algorithm -I../../include -I../../src/include -I../../../ExternalDependencies/STL/STLport-5.2.1/stlport -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-stack-protector -fPIC -DFRFXLL_MAJOR=5 -DFRFXLL_MINOR=2 -DFRFXLL_REVISION=0 -DFRFXLL_BUILD=0   -c -o FRFXLLDuplicateHandle.o FRFXLLDuplicateHandle.cpp
ar rv ../../lib/libFRFXLL.a FRFXLLDuplicateHandle.o
a - FRFXLLDuplicateHandle.o
g++ -O2 -I../algorithm -I../../include -I../../src/include -I../../../ExternalDependencies/STL/STLport-5.2.1/stlport -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-stack-protector -fPIC -DFRFXLL_MAJOR=5 -DFRFXLL_MINOR=2 -DFRFXLL_REVISION=0 -DFRFXLL_BUILD=0   -c -o FRFXLLCreateLibraryContext.o FRFXLLCreateLibraryContext.cpp
ar rv ../../lib/libFRFXLL.a FRFXLLCreateLibraryContext.o
a - FRFXLLCreateLibraryContext.o
g++ -O2 -I../algorithm -I../../include -I../../src/include -I../../../ExternalDependencies/STL/STLport-5.2.1/stlport -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-stack-protector -fPIC -DFRFXLL_MAJOR=5 -DFRFXLL_MINOR=2 -DFRFXLL_REVISION=0 -DFRFXLL_BUILD=0   -c -o FRFXLLCreateFeatureSetFromRaw.o FRFXLLCreateFeatureSetFromRaw.cpp
ar rv ../../lib/libFRFXLL.a FRFXLLCreateFeatureSetFromRaw.o
a - FRFXLLCreateFeatureSetFromRaw.o
rm FRFXLLCreateContext.o FRFXLLCreateFeatureSetInPlaceFromRaw.o FRFXLLDuplicateHandle.o FRFXLLCreateLibraryContext.o FRFXLLCreateFeatureSet.o FRFXLLGetLibraryVersion.o FRFXLLCreateFeatureSetInPlace.o FRFXLLCreateFeatureSetFromRaw.o FRFXLLExport.o
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/work/iso_conv/FingerJetFXOSE-master/src/libFRFXLL/src/libFRFXLL'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/work/iso_conv/FingerJetFXOSE-master/src/libFRFXLL'
make -C src/libfjfx
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/work/iso_conv/FingerJetFXOSE-master/src/libfjfx'
g++ -O2  -Wl,--strip-all -I../../include -I../libFRFXLL/include -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-stack-protector -fPIC -shared -nodefaultlibs -Wl,--version-script=fjfx.vers -Wl,-soname,libfjfx.so.5 -L../libFRFXLL/lib -Wl,--whole-archive -lFRFXLL fjfx.cpp -o ../../lib/libfjfx.so.5.2.0
‘../../lib/libfjfx.so.5’ -> ‘libfjfx.so.5.2.0’
‘../../lib/libfjfx.so’ -> ‘libfjfx.so.5’
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/work/iso_conv/FingerJetFXOSE-master/src/libfjfx'
make -C samples/fjfxSample
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/work/iso_conv/FingerJetFXOSE-master/samples/fjfxSample'
cc fjfxSample.c -g -O0 -I../../include -L../../lib -lfjfx  -o ../../bin/fjfxSample
/usr/bin/ld: ../../bin/fjfxSample: hidden symbol `__aeabi_uidiv' in /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/libgcc.a(_udivsi3.o) is referenced by DSO
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:66: recipe for target '../../bin/fjfxSample' failed
make[1]: *** [../../bin/fjfxSample] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/work/iso_conv/FingerJetFXOSE-master/samples/fjfxSample'
Makefile:50: recipe for target 'samples/fjfxSample' failed
make: *** [samples/fjfxSample] Error 2
pi@raspberrypi ~/work/iso_conv/FingerJetFXOSE-master $
```

Unfortunately i am not able to fix this error. I think it is just something small, but my fixes did not work.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1):

It works if i compile it with:

```
make CC=g++
```